# Google Plus - Plus One Button Policy

Tags: google-plus, google-plus-one

We are an ecommmerce retailer and after reading this privacy policy we got seriously confused. The feature we wants to implement on our website it to provide discount for sharing and plus one our google plus page so would need serious help as we don't want to get in trouble with this policies. We wants to give discount in behalf of plus one to our google plus page so that they will receive our promotions and other marketing details on their profile so whether this policy affect us or not ? We understand the importance for plus one our website pages as it will affect google search ranking but we don't think that it will affect anything with plus one google plus page. We need serious help to move ahead with implementing this feature as soon as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the Google+ +1 Button Policy: "Publishers may not promote prizes, monies, or monetary equivalents in exchange for Google+ button clicks."

(https://developers.google.com/+/plugins/buttons-policy)

Unfortunately, your intention to offer a discount in exchange for a +1 is a direct violation of this.

You should consider starting a Google+ Page and engaging with your users through the page. You can promote your business through your posts and get more followers.  Also, with a Google+ Page, you can create a Badge for your site that will link back to your Page to increase social engagement.

(https://developers.google.com/+/plugins/badge/)

Comment: Thanks for your confirming that it will directly violate. Anyways its good to know from starting as we haven't started any work on it. Again Thanks for your time. Appreciate it.